# How do you click on a checkbox from a list of checkboxes via Selenium/Webdriver in Java?

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I'm using Selenium 2 (Webdriver) for automating tests on a webpage. However I wonder if there is way to check checkbox from the list of checkboxes using webdriver framework?

I tried this code but no avail:

```
IWebElement box = ffDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Adde_div']"));
List<IWebElement> chkbox = box.FindElements(By.TagName("input"));
ffDriver.FindElement(By.Id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Add_lstCategory_0"));         
//chkbox.g(2).click();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you already know the id of the checkbox, you can use this method to click select it:

```
string checkboxXPath = "//input[contains(@id, 'lstCategory_0')]"
IWebElement elementToClick = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(checkboxXPath));
elementToClick.Click();
```

Assuming that you have several checkboxes on the page with similar ids, you may need to change 'lstCategory_0' to something more specific.

This is written in C#, but it shouldn't be difficult to adapt to other languages.  Also, if you edit your post with some more information, I can fine-tune this example better.

Let me know if this works!

---

I've visited the site and successfully interacted with the checkboxes in the dropdown widget using this code:

```
/** Set XPath Variables **/
string dropdownWidgetXPath = "//span[contains(@id, 'selInd')]";
string checkboxXPath = "//input[contains(@id, 'selInd')]";

/** Navigate to the page **/
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.jobserve.com/us/en/Job-Search/");

/** Click the dropdown widget **/
IWebElement dropdownWidgetElement = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(dropdownWidgetXPath));
dropdownWidgetElement.Click();

/** Identify all checkboxes present **/
var allCheckboxes = driver.FindElements(By.XPath(checkboxXPath));

/** Click each checkbox and wait so that results are visible **/
foreach(IWebElement checkbox in allCheckboxes)
{
     checkbox.Click();
     System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
}
```

Comment: if you go to this site http://www.jobserve.com/us/en/Job-Search/ and click on the dropdownlist (Industry) and i am trying to select few check-boxes from there..

Comment: i tried your code but did not click on the checkbox id which i wanted to be

Comment: I use ChromeDriver and your solution with checkbox.Click() does not work. I have to use checkbox.SendKeys(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Space); to check or uncheck the checkboxes.

Answer (score 1):

In Selenium webdriver you can do it like this :

All the check-boxes must be having some unique identifier then you can simply find it out by Id If they dont have a unique id (This is what I encountered while testing a web application) then it must be having some title and name attribute (or some other attribute).

Then you can try this :

```
driver = new FirefoxDriver(); 
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='mycheckboxgroup' and @title='movies']")).click();    
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='mycheckboxgroup' and @title='songs']")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

> By id of the checkbox you could use following code:

```
IWebElement elementToClick = driver.FindElement(By.ID(ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Add_lstCategory_0));
elementToClick.Click();
```

If you don't know id then use below code by xpath:

```
String checkbox = "//input[@type='checkbox']"
IWebElement elementToClick = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(checkbox ));
elementToClick.Click();
```

Answer (score 0):

The code in `selenium` is simple:

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeToHoldOn)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists((By.ClassName("ckb"))));
IWebElement dropdownWidgetElement = driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("ckb"));
dropdownWidgetElement.Click();
Thread.Sleep(1000);
var allCheckboxes = driver.FindElements(By.ClassName("ckb"));
foreach (IWebElement checkbox in allCheckboxes) {
  checkbox.Click();
  System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(250);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I check and uncheck all my boxes, it has to have an Id or class.

Id example:

```
driver.FindElement(By.Id("someid")).click();
```

ClassName examaple:

```
driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("someid")).click();
```

Its short, its sweet and more importantly it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this piece of code written in java

```
String checkboxes = "//*[@type='checkbox']";
List<WebElement> elementToClick = driver.findElements(By.xpath(checkboxes));
for (WebElement AllCheck : elementToClick) {
    AllCheck.click();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Java, Clicking on multiple checkboxes at a time using the loop.**

```
**Sample Xpath :**

CheckBox1 Xpath : //input[@class='mycheck' and @id='1']
CheckBox2 Xpath : //input[@class='mycheck' and @id='2']
```

> Get all the elements checkbox using findelements:
>
> List WebElement ele =
>   driver.findElements(By.xpath("//input[@class='mycheck']"));

Make the Xpath as string by leaving the ID and assign the ID as i.

```
for(int i=1; i<=ele.size(); i++) { driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@class='mycheck' and @id='" +  + i + "']")).click(); }
```

i gets the value for every loop and the xpath matches the checkbox and click's it.

Answer (score 0):

You can select each of the radio buttons/checkboxes by selecting the element which contains them and iterating through each one just like an array.

For example, here a ul element contains some radio buttons. I select the ul element first, then I can select each radio by using the correct index (inside the [])

```
 //Select the ul containing the radio buttons I want to click/select

   var ul = driver.FindElement(By.Id("ul_containing_radio_buttons"));

   //use forloop to click each button in turn         
   for (var i = 2; i <= 0; i--)
         {
            var button= ul.FindElements(By.TagName("input"))[i];
            //i is the index of the radio button in out ul element
            button.Click();
         }
```