# How do I click on checkbox using selenium web driver in Java?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

How do I click on checkbox using selenium web driver in Java?

Code is:

```
<div class="icheckbox_square-purple" aria-checked="false" 
  aria-disabled="false" style="position: relative;">
<input type="checkbox" class="check initialChk" value="7" 
  id="7" style="position: absolute; opacity: 0;">
<ins class="iCheck-helper" 
  style="position: absolute; 
    top: 0%; left: 0%; display: block; 
    width: 100%; height: 100%; 
    margin: 0px; padding: 0px; 
    border: 0px; opacity: 0; 
    background: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
</ins>
</div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Click Check-box from the list of Check boxes via Selenium/Webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11888786/click-check-box-from-the-list-of-check-boxes-via-selenium-webdriver)

Answer (score 0):

First you have to find this element, for example by xPath, and then do click() action on this element.

Possible duplicate:
[How to select checkboxes using selenium java webdriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14682763/how-to-select-checkboxes-using-selenium-java-webdriver)

Answer (score 0):

```
WebElement chk = driver.findElement(By.className("initialChk"));     
chk.click();
```

Comment: what is the error? Do you have multiple check-boxes with the same ID or class name on the page? If yes, use findElements method instead of findElement.

Answer (score 0):

In the first step you have to locate your checkbox by some locator, here I'm using id as an element locator.

By ChkName = By.id("7");
WebElement chkBox = driver.findElement(ChkName).click();

That's all it's simple!

Comment: Its not working.show me this error.  Type mismatch: cannot convert from void to WebElement on chkname

Comment: try By ChkName = By.id("7");driver.findElement(ChkName).click(); Its working

Comment: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException:

Answer (score 0):

```
WebElement box = driver.FindElement(By.className("initialChk"));
    {
        if(!box.Selected)
            box.Click();
    }
```

Comment: This would be a better answer if it included an explanation along with the code.

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate issue. You can try this :

```
driver.findElement(By.id("idOfTheElement")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from other answers, you can use this;

```
your_web_driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='checkbox']")).click();
```

to check **every** check box in a page.