# How to select a check box in selenium webdriver 2?

Tags: java, selenium, checkbox

Here is the [site](https://www.olx.ua/account/?ref[0][action]=myaccount&ref[0][method]=index#register). I need to select checkbox in selenium webdriver.
 [Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y3nAy.png)

```html
<div class="login-form__checkbox">
  <div class="fblock active">
    <div class="focusbox">
      <span class="abs" style="width:0px; height:0px; overflow:hidden; font-size:0px; zoom:1;">
        <input id="checkbox_accept-terms" type="checkbox" name="register[rules]"/>
      </span>
      <label class="icon f_checkbox inlblk vtop selected" relname="register[rules]"               for="checkbox_accept-terms"/>
      <label class="selected" for="checkbox_accept-terms">
        <strong>Rules</strong>                                                                                                                                                              
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("checkbox_accept-terms")).click();
```

and

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@id='checkbox_accept-terms']/div[3]/div/div/label[1]")).click();
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Click Check-box from the list of Check boxes via Selenium/Webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11888786/click-check-box-from-the-list-of-check-boxes-via-selenium-webdriver)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried clicking the `INPUT` directly but it didn't allow that for some reason. You can just click the `LABEL` and it checks the box. This code works.

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("label[for='checkbox_accept-terms']")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

This  is the xpath that chrome gives while inspecting element.

```
//*[@id="registerForm"]/div[3]/div/div/label[1]
```

This is the relative xpath that worked for me:

```
//label[@class="icon f_checkbox inlblk vtop"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can perform the task using JavaScriptExecutor too, with the same locators you tried with. Look at the code snippet below:

```
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("checkbox_accept-terms"));
jse.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```