# select checkbox using selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

i need to select checkbox which is having same ids 
HTML:

```
<label class="table-checkbox-label" for="record-12034">
<input id="record-12034" class="table-checkbox" type="checkbox"/>
</label>
</td>
<td>91363007</td>
<td>EC4N</td>
<td>true</td>
<td>ACTIVE</td>
</tr>
<tr data-id="12201">
<td>
<label class="table-checkbox-label" for="record-12201">
<input id="record-12201" class="table-checkbox" type="checkbox"/>
</label>
</td>
```

[list of checkboxes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LTtFN.png). 
i will send contract id to filterbox below the contract ID which is like a autocomplete box.so it will give result based on input.
[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OjnwW.png)
But here my selenium code is clickin on 1st checkbox from the list of checkboxes as shown in image 1.

Please any suggestions

Edit:
:
code for keyword function:

```
public void filter(String objectName,String testData) throws InterruptedException,IOException {

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15);

          wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(".//*[@id='content']/div[7]/table/thead/tr[2]/td[2]/input")));//wait for textbox

          driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='content']/div[7]/table/thead/tr[2]/td[2]/input")).sendKeys(testData);//send data to textbox
          System.out.print("Text box is now visible");
          driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[starts-with(@id,'record')]")).click();//click on checkbox 
          driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='content']/div[7]/table/thead/tr[2]/td[2]/input")).clear();//clear textbox
        }
```

Code for reading excel file:

```
    public void ASRTaccounts() throws IOException, InterruptedException, EncryptedDocumentException, InvalidFormatException, AWTException {
                keyword = new keywords();
                 List<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();
                    File file = new File("C:\\RDMT test\\rdmt_test\\RDMT_\\LeadSuite.xlsx");
                    Workbook workbook  = WorkbookFactory.create(file);
                    DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter();
                    Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheet("login");
                    for (Row row : sheet) {
                       for (Cell cell : row) {
                          data.add(formatter.formatCellValue(cell));
                       }
                    }
                System.out.println(data);
                for (int i=3;i<data.size();i++){

                    if (data.get(i).equals("filter")){
                        String key = (String) data.get(i);
                        String testData = (String) data.get(i+1);
                        String objectName = (String) data.get(i+2);
                        System.out.println(key);
                        System.out.println(testData);
                        System.out.println(objectName);
                        keyword.filter(objectName,testData);

                    }
```

Comment: So the problem is that you're not finding the correct checkbox? Could you show us your code? Can't you do `driver.getElement(By.id("record-12034"))` or something similar?

Comment: @ToddSewell i am sending contract ID to text box using excel file for which i am using Apache POI. i have set of data to send for which i need to select checkbox and then need to clear filterbox.

Comment: @LolCoder아카쉬 i have tried using start with xpath, list ,is selected. the issue is it is selecting the checkbox but before i send value to text box and that too first checkbox only.

Comment: And what is the problem with the solution I proposed? And again, where is you *Java* code?

Comment: @ToddSewell this is my code which worked fine once only i dnt know after that it started behaving like this issue . i have added code in question for keyword function and reading excel file too.

Comment: @ToddSewell i have edited the answer , this is a roadblock for me but it is not getting resolved. i dnt know where i am doing mistake . hope i satisfy your requirements now. the problem with the solution u proposed is i need to send data from excel file . else i know ur solution is going to work like charm

Comment: Okay in the code where you interact with the driver, is there a variable or something that holds the id that you want to check?

Comment: yes in the code --> this line driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='content']/div[7]/table/thead/tr[2]/td[2]/input")).sendKeys(testData);//send data to textbox, it holds my data e.g. contract id .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Click Check-box from the list of Check boxes via Selenium/Webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11888786/click-check-box-from-the-list-of-check-boxes-via-selenium-webdriver)

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in selecting checkbox you want to click.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[starts-with(@id,'record')]")).click();
```

This will find ALL elements which have "record" in their ID (these are all checkboxes in your case) and return ONLY the first one. 
You need to select exact one checkbox you want to click by using something like this `driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//input[@id='record-idofcheckboxyouwanttoclick']")).click();`

EDIT: Oh, now I see where is the problem. Not sure how your HTML after filtering looks like, but you should use xpath to find `<td>` element which contains your inputs/numbers which you sent, and then find his `<label>` preceding sibling which contains `<input>` (checkbox) you want to click.

Comment: thanks for this . but this will only work if i give this directly in my code . By.xpath("//*[@id='record-12033']"))).click();.. but instead of that i am passing testdata from excel file and need to click the checkbox based on input. so everytime for any value i can't modify my code . i have set of inputs to send to that textbox.

Comment: after filter my HTML looks same as i have given . i am going to give a try to your suggestion. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Checkbox appearing just before the text box can be selected using the [preceding](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPath/Axes/preceding) xpath function. Try following and let me know, if you still face the same issue:

```
public void filter(String objectName,String testData) throws   InterruptedException,IOException {

      WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15);
      wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(".//*[@id='content']/div[7]/table/thead/tr[2]/td[2]/input")));//wait for textbox

      driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='content']/div[7]/table/thead/tr[2]/td[2]/input")).sendKeys(testData);//send data to textbox
      System.out.print("Text box is now visible");
      driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='content']/div[7]/table/thead/tr[2]/td[2]/input/preceding::input[1]")).click();//click on checkbox 
      driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='content']/div[7]/table/thead/tr[2]/td[2]/input/preceding::input[1]")).clear();//clear textbox
    }
```