# How to select checkbox using selenium web driver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait

In my web-page (or popup), there are multiple input-boxes and checkbox. Input boxes and check-boxes are in separate div tag. Here is my html code:

```
<div class="modal-body-large">
    <div class="col-md-12 step-forms custom-tab-content">
        <form class="form-horizontal form-sections">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Username<span class="red">*</span></label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input name="userId" class="form-control custom-form-control" type="text" placeholder="Username" value="">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Email<span class="red">*</span></label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input name="email" class="form-control custom-form-control" type="text" placeholder="Email" value="">
                </div>
            </div>
            .....
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12 step-forms custom-tab-content">
        <form class="form-horizontal"><span class="help-block" style="font-size: small;"><i>Note: Optional</i></span>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div>
                    <div class="form-sections">
                        <ul>
                            <li>Select permissions</li>
                            <li>
                                <input type="checkbox" id="permissions1565851434728" name="permissions">
                                <label for="permissions1565851434728" class="xh-highlight">Select all</label>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <div class="searchbox-container">
                            <div class="check-list">
                                <ul>
                                    <li title="">
                                        <input type="checkbox" id="371565851434728" name="permissions" value="Add/Update Network Security">
                                        <label for="371565851434728" class="">Add/Update Network Security</label>
                                    </li>
                                    <li title="">
                                        <input type="checkbox" id="111565851434728" name="permissions" value="Add/Update Permissions">
                                        <label for="111565851434728" class="">Add/Update Permissions</label>
                                    </li>
                                    .....
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-sections">
                    <ul>
                        <li>Select roles</li>
                        <li>
                            <input type="checkbox" id="roles1565851434730" name="roles">
                            <label for="roles1565851434730">Select all</label>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="searchbox-container">
                        <div class="check-list">
                            <ul>
                                <li title="Update User Details,Create User,Create Project">
                                    <input type="checkbox" id="role-c98974c6-a4b1-4428-9d9e-7df9f00acd351565851434730" name="roles" value="test">
                                    <label for="role-c98974c6-a4b1-4428-9d9e-7df9f00acd351565851434730">test</label>
                                </li>
                                .....
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I come to this page, I'm successfully able to enter text in input fields. When it comes to select checkbox, I have to give complete xpath to that checkbox. Like, if I want to select checkbox Select all, I am giving xpath as

```
"/html/body/div[@id='app']/div[@class='_loading-overlay']/main/div[@class='container-fluid search_table_container']/div[1]/div[@class='identity-management']/div[@class='row identity-list']/div/div[@class='filter-head col-md-12']/div[@class='search_right']/div[@class='modal fade in']/div[@class='modal-dialog modal-lg']/div[@class='modal-content']/div[@class='modal-body-large']/div[@class='col-md-12 step-forms custom-tab-content'][2]/form[@class='form-horizontal']/div[@class='col-md-6'][1]/div/div[@class='form-sections']/ul/li[2]/label"
```

My concern is there any alternate to do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Click Check-box from the list of Check boxes via Selenium/Webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11888786/click-check-box-from-the-list-of-check-boxes-via-selenium-webdriver)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To `click()` on the *check box* associated with the `<label>` as **Select all** as the desired element is within a *Modal Dialog* you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `elementToBeClickable()` and you can use the following [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `xpath`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//li[text()='Select permissions']//following::li[1]//label"))).click();
  ```

Comment: It worked. If i want to select specific permission then only xpath i have to change. Right?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the text of the uncle element. To get `Select all` under `Select permissions` you can use

```
//li[contains(., 'Select permissions')]/following-sibling::li/label
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `xpath`, and use `WebDriverWait` for make the element exist then use `Actions`, try this :

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//*[@type='checkbox' and contains(@id,'permissions')]")));
WebElement elmnt = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@type='checkbox' and contains(@id,'permissions')]"));
Actions act = new Actions(driver);
act.moveToElement(elmnt).click().build().perform();
```

Or

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("(//*[@type='checkbox'])[1]")));
WebElement elmnt = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//*[@type='checkbox'])[1]"));
Actions act = new Actions(driver);
act.moveToElement(elmnt).click().build().perform();
```

Change the `[1]` to `[2]` etc, if you want another checkbox.

Comment: i used second one it says org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: element not interactable

Comment: I've updated the code, add `WebDriverWait` and use `Actions`.

Comment: Got an error org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for element to be clickable: By.xpath: //*[@type='checkbox' and contains(@id,'permissions')] (tried for 20 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)

Answer (score 0):

Selecting a checkbox is similar to clicking a button. I see there is `id` for all the checkboxes and also `value` field for some checkboxes. So you can use the following methods to accomplish what you need.

Select checkbox using `id` by passing it to the `XPath`,

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='permissions1565851434728']")).sendKeys(Keys.SPACE);
```

You can click checkbox instead of sending keys like the following,

```
WebElement checkBox = driver.findElement(By.id("permissions1565851434728"));
checkBox.click();
```

Select checkbox using `value` by passing it to the `CSSSelector`,

```
WebElement checkBox = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[value='Add/Update Network Security']"));
checkBox.click();
```

And if there are 2 checkboxes you can use as follows,

```
driver.FindElements(By.xpath("(//input[@type='checkbox'])[1]"));
driver.FindElements(By.xpath("(//input[@type='checkbox'])[2]")); ...
```

Selenium WebDriver uses the native methods of browsers to interact with the web components. Be that as it may, some times the web components do not react to these native methods. In such cases, your most solid option is JavaScript.

So you can try the following JavaScript to interact with the web element,

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[value='Add/Update Network Security']"));

((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

And also you can try with `WebDriverWait` said by [***DebanjanB***](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57516655/8440358).

Comment: Select checkbox using value thrown Exception i.e., org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: element not interactable

Comment: Select checkbox using id And those id changes. that id changes on time.

Comment: findElements also says org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: element not interactable

Answer (score 0):

1. For `Select Roles` checkbox:

   ```
   //li[text()='Select roles']/following-sibling::li/input
   ```

   [image]
2. For `Select Permissions` checkbox the same approach:

   ```
   //li[text()='Select permissions']/following-sibling::li/input
   ```
3. [`following-sibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes/following-sibling) is XPath Axis returning the next node having the same parent and `text()` is [XPath function](https://docs.experitest.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=40044727) matching node text content